# Windbg treating pointers as signed integers

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windbg

```
struct Node
{
struct NodeY NY;
int data;
};
```

When I do this, for an instance pointer 'N' of that structure

```
2: kd> ?poi(poi(N))
Evaluate expression: -70368698399456 = ffffc000`02ba8520
```

basically I want to use something like this

```
bp igdkmd64!KmRender+0x199 ".if (@@(N) > 0x1){}.else {gc}"
```

So, most of the cases it is true, but as windbg treats it has signed integer, the above conditional breakpoint is always false as @@(N) is always computed as negative.

How can I get a quantity comparison of 2 memory addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kd> ?? (**int64**) `@@(ffffc00002ba8520) > 1`
**bool false**
kd> ?? (**unsigned int64**) `@@(ffffc00002ba8520) > 1`
**bool true**

Comment: Perfect!. I should have thought about typecasting, but nevertheless, Thanks!